# Entry doesn't follow available space (screen size)

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, maui-windows

I cannot resolve the sizing issue.
I created a small example to show it.
I have an entry field and a button:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Frame>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">
            <Entry/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="ok"/>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

It is simplified layout, please follow this structure.

When I input some text that is longer than the entry's width it works fine, but after I made the window smaller, the entry (input field) extends itself and move the button out of the view

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to use `HorisontalOptions="Fill"` for entry, it did not work

Comment: The entry is acting as it should, the grid's second column is causing your issue.

Give the second column in your grid the size of your button width (i.e. "50"). Leaving it as auto gives the first column priority in taking up all the space it needs and just leaving whatever is left for the second column.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I’ve just tried this solution, but it doesn’t resolve the issue.

Comment: 1) When you try a suggestion, and it does not work for you, add an UPDATE section to your question. Show the exact code you have now. 2) As a test, remove the `Frame` around the Grid. Does this behave correctly? If so, this is likely a bug in Maui; it did not re-calculate the layout correctly when the window size changed. 3) You might try [.Net Preview 8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0). Download from link. Then, somewhere in VS menus is "Manage Preview Features", to enable use of this.

Comment: @DevenCC: Your explanation is not correct. "Auto" sizes as needed. "*" takes any UNUSED space. Nevertheless, when encountering a bug like this, Trying a fixed size is a good alternative; it often works around layout issues.

Comment: @AntonDanko Your code is correct. Ignore what DevenCC told you, it is completely wrong. What OS are you testing on? What is your visual studio version? What .NET version are you using in your project?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Frames are bugged, but this is the StackLayout. My last release was with MAUI 7.0.86, when this bug was fixed. As far as I know, this issue was later introduced again (this is why I am not updating) and later fixed. And I know that it was present at some point in .NET 8 preview, and got fixed there as well.

Comment: @H.A.H. I test it on Windows OS, using .net 7, Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.6.4,  Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.09032. maui-windows:              7.0.86/7.0.100 VS 17.6.33815.320

Comment: @AntonDanko You are fine. Do not change the version. Change the Frame to Border, and you will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is correct.

Run: `dotnet workload list`

And see if your maui version is 7.0.86. (VS 17.6.5)
(For this I am 100% sure)

Or try to get 7.0.92.
(Not sure for this)

Everything in between is not ok. Everything before is not ok.

Edit: Your version 7.0.86 (VS 17.6.4) is perfectly fine, do not risk updating.
Change `Frame` to `Border`.

Comment: My maui version is 7.0.86. (VS 17.6.5) . But I run in windows 10. And I can reproduce op's problem.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Depends how much you resize the window with frame. On larger screens it does not show, on smaller it does. Border with padding does the same without this issue, and does not mess my tap events in Android. (Frames are totally non-usable in 7.0.86, but Grids have no problems)

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice the problem is frame. Delete the Frame or use the border instead of it both work.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Unless, you update MAUI. This here is the serious Auto-Star problem: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13993. If you make a mistake to update, the downgrade is very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">` will make the grid's width depend on the width of it children (the button and the entry). And when you input the text, the entry will increase its width.

So you can detect the window's sizechanged event to set the entry's widthrequest.

In the xaml:

```
<StackLayout >
  <Frame>
      <Grid x:Name="grid" ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">
          <Entry x:Name="entry" Grid.Column="0"/>
          <Button x:Name="button" Grid.Column="1" Text="ok"/>
      </Grid>
  </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

And override the page's OnHandlerChanged event:

```
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
        Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window window = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window)App.Current.Windows.First<Window>().Handler.PlatformView;
        window.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            entry.WidthRequest = grid.Width-button.Width;
        };
#endif
    }
```

**Update:**

The problem is the Frame. Delete it or use Border instead of Frame will work.

Comment: I really want to know your Visual Studio and .NET version.

Comment: I got a very complex layout with so many elements and I can't describe the behavior for all of them, it's too complicated.